# Drag and Drop ( Copy ) in another Div is lining up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a Drag and Drop project where when dropping an image in another Div, it has to stay in the same place where I left it.
The problem is the img are lining up the left.

[image: Drag img to drop it in div Conteudo]

[image: The img go to the left side]

HTML CODE :

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/testednd.css" /> <!-- CSS das div's -->
        <script src="js/testednd.js"></script> <!-- Script clickImagem -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="conteudo-left" style="position:static; left:10px; top:20px; width:300; height:660; z-index:-1; overflow: auto">
            <form name="form_dnd_left" border = 1>
                <ul> 
                    <li><img id="drag1" src="images/Comp3.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo" id="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><!-- abrimos a div conteudo do meio-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
    #conteudo-left{
    width:300px;
    height:660px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#conteudo{
    width:600px;
    height:460px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    .columns {
    }

}
```

JavaScript Code

```
///Drag'n Drop functions
function allowDrop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) 
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}

function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
    var original = document.getElementById(data);
    copyimg.src = original.src;
    ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
}
```

Can somebody help me??
Thanks for all !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the drop event you get the x and y coords of the mouse and set the style to be absolute in that position. Note that the top left corner of the image will snap to the exact coord of the mouse pointer. See below:

```js
///Drag'n Drop functions
function allowDrop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) 
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}

function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var x = ev.clientX;
    var y = ev.clientY;
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
    var original = document.getElementById(data);
    copyimg.src = original.src;
    ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
    
    copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top: "+y+"px; left:"+x+"px;");
}
```

```css
#conteudo-left{
    width:150px;
    height:330px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#conteudo{
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/testednd.css" /> <!-- CSS das div's -->
        <script src="js/testednd.js"></script> <!-- Script clickImagem -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="conteudo-left" style="position:static; left:10px; top:20px; width:300; height:660; z-index:-1; overflow: auto">
            <form name="form_dnd_left" border = 1>
                <ul> 
                    <li><img id="drag1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="asdfasdf" /></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo" id="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sora glad it works but make sure to see the change i just did, i used the wrong css style

Comment: How can I, when drag a img, me mouse stay on center of image, its possible in this case?? Like this link :
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#cursor-style

Comment: @Sora you would have to offset it by half the dimensions of the image.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

From the event you can get the position of the drag and minus the offset of the parent, thus we can drop it in that exact location.

```
function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
    var parent = document.createElement("conteudo");
    var original = document.getElementById(data);
    copyimg.src = original.src;
    copyimg.style.position = "absolute";
    copyimg.style.left = ev.clientX - ev.target.offsetLeft+"px";
    copyimg.style.top = ev.clientY - ev.target.offsetTop+"px";
    ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
}
```

**Old Answer:**

Do you want something like this?

CSS used to make this is:

```
padding-left: 150px;
padding-top: 125px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

So I gave half of the width and height as padding so that the images get positioned there! also I am using `box-sizing:border-box` so that the padding does not get added to the dimensions of the `div`.

**Note:** *I have reduced the dimesions of the boxes so that they fit perfectly inside the demo window, please set the `padding-top and`padding-left` to about half of the width of the respective dimensions!*

```js
///Drag'n Drop functions
function allowDrop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) 
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}

function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
    var parent = document.createElement("conteudo");
    var original = document.getElementById(data);
    copyimg.src = original.src;
    copyimg.style.position = "absolute";
    copyimg.style.left = ev.clientX - ev.target.offsetLeft+"px";
    copyimg.style.top = ev.clientY - ev.target.offsetTop+"px";
    ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
}
```

```css
#conteudo-left{
    width:150px;
    height:330px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#conteudo{
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/testednd.css" /> <!-- CSS das div's -->
        <script src="js/testednd.js"></script> <!-- Script clickImagem -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="conteudo-left" style="position:static; left:10px; top:20px; width:300; height:660; z-index:-1; overflow: auto">
            <form name="form_dnd_left" border = 1>
                <ul> 
                    <li><img id="drag1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="asdfasdf" /></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo" id="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost this, however I'd like to drop the image anywhere on the div, move it freely. Thanks for answer !!

Comment: Sorry for bad english too

Comment: @Sora Updated my answer!

Comment: Yeah !! now it work, I learn this command "ev.target.offsetLeft+"px" ", thanks @Naren !!

Comment: How can I, when drag a img, me mouse stay on center of image, its possible in this case?? Like this link :
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#cursor-style